# Array of ints - does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I try to make an array of ints:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    int[] levelsSolvedCounter = new int[3];
    levelsSolvedCounter[0] = 10;
}
```

But I get an error:

> The name 'levelsSolvedCounter' does not exist in the current context

Although in online compiler (https://dotnetfiddle.net/) the code works just fine.

Comment: That code *wouldn't* work fine in any normal C# compiler. Your second statement isn't a declaration, so should be part of a method, constructor or other function member.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://dotnetfiddle.net/S6hZje. The code in your question cannot be the same code you put into dotnetfiddle.

Comment: I assume you put those lines inside of the Main method of the online compiler which is fine, but here they are not inside of a method which makes all the difference.

Comment: @juharr, yes, you're right. I didn't know I can't declare it this way.

Comment: @ExConfessor `I didn't know I can't declare it this way`  Your declaration isn't the issue. `int[] levelsSolvedCounter = new int[3];` is a declaration, and is allowed at the class level.  `levelsSolvedCounter[0] = 10;` is *not* a declaration, it is a statement, and cannot exist at the class level.

Answer (score 4):

You're not allowed to write implementation on the top-level of a class. You need to define a method first.

The `levelsSolvedCounter[0] = 10;` is implementation. So you need to define it within a method.

You could try something like:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    int[] levelsSolvedCounter = new int[3];

    void Update()
    {
        levelsSolvedCounter[0] = 10;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work just fine:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    int[] levelsSolvedCounter = new int[3];

    void Update()
    {           
       levelsSolvedCounter[0] = 10;
    }
}
```

In C#, all logic needs to be part of a method/property/etc., it cannot be directly on the class level. Only data fields and other class members can. So while `int[] levelsSolvedCounter = new int[3];` is actually a valid class private data member definition, the `levelSolvedCounter[0] = 10;` is invalid and must be inside a method. In this case I used the `Update` method, which is what gets executed to update the game object state on each frame. I kept the data member outside of the method, so it is not created on each frame again and again.

Comment: `Start` would have been a better choice than `Update` IMO, but it isn't wrong.